# MySql. What is there error on this insert+select+where statement?

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with this statement? It works with sqlite and MS sql (last time i tested it)

I would like a select unless there is no match with name or email. Then i would like to insert. I have it as one statement because its easy to keep concurrent safe as one statement. (its not that complex of a statement).

```
INSERT INTO `user_data` (
`last_login_ip`, `login_date`,
...) SELECT 
@0,
@14 WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM `user_data` WHERE `name` = @15 OR 
`unconfirmed_email` = @16 LIMIT 1);
```

Exception

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM `user_data` WHERE `name` = 'thename' OR 
`unconfirmed' at line 31
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no `FROM` clause in your `SELECT`. If you look carefully at the [documentation for `SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) you can see that although `FROM` is optional, if there is a `WHERE` clause then the `FROM` is required:

```
SELECT ...
[FROM table_references
[WHERE ...]
...]
```

If you don't need a table you can use `FROM DUAL`.